# Access Google traffic in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, traffic

I wonder if there is a way for me to access the google traffic in my Earth Engine code so it shows up on my map? I've only seen pure javascript which I don't know how to implement in Earth engine.

Comment: The only way to use Earth Engine is via its APIs, JavaScript or Python, so in order to use it you have to learn how. There are plenty of examples and tutorials. Start from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine. Google traffic dataset is not available in Earth Engine